# Finding railroad maps for Germany in late 19th century?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, emigration, maps, bremen

I am studying a group of immigrants who came to the northeastern United States from Saxony in the 1870s to 1890s.  Many of them were skilled workers all recruited from the same area specifically for their skills in the textile industries.

Of the "second wave" immigrants (1800 to 1920), James Beidler, in his book [The Family Tree German Genealogy Guide](http://www.shopfamilytree.com/the-family-tree-german-genealogy-guide-group), says on page 33:

> Rhine-to-Rotterdam was no longer the emigrant superhighway. Immigrants used other rivers and, as the nineteenth century wore on, railroads to get to the ports of Bremerhaven (the harbor for the ancient city-state of Bremen) and Hamburg.

The United States passenger lists for these families indicate that most of these families departed from Bremen, so I don't have embarkation records for them.

I'd like to put the information I glean from the records created in the USA in context by locating the towns on a map.  Finding railroad schedules, maps, and travel guides for the period would give me a better idea of the time it might take to travel to the ports and would help me correlate the information I have.

Comment: There appear to be a few Emigration Centre museums/exhibitions in Germany, including [Bremen](http://www.stattreisen-bremen.de/stadtfuehrungen/thema/auflistung/themenrundgaenge/aufbruch-in-die-fremde.html) (in German), [Bremerhaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Emigration_Center) and [Hamburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BallinStadt) that might be helpful, if you hadn't seen those already. A search for "Aufbruch in die Fremde" (from the Bremen exhibit) brings up a book and video (on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJnoRFUWvlc), in German), among other things.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I've found so far:

- Wikipedia, [History of Rail Transport in Germany, The Länderbahn era (1871 to 1920)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_rail_transport_in_Germany)  and [Geschichte der Eisenbahn in Deutschland](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschichte_der_Eisenbahn_in_Deutschland#L.C3.A4nderbahnzeit_1871_bis_1920) on de.wikipedia.org
- Wikipedia, [Royal Saxon State Railways](http://Royal%20Saxon%20State%20Railways) has a map from 1902 (a good starting point, but a little too late for my period)
- [European Transportation Maps of the 19th Century](http://www.lib.uchicago.edu/e/collections/maps/eurotransport/) at the University of Chicago Library
- [FEEFHS Map Library](http://feefhs.org/maplibrary.html) (The Foundation for East European Family History Studies)
- [Historical GIS Research Network](http://www.hgis.org.uk/resources.htm)